# .htaccess don't work in azure

Tags: .htaccess, azure, web-config

i try to put my .htaccess (that work on linux server) in my azure end not work.
I think the issue is that I had to use web.config structure, so I try also this, but now http return 500.

My .htaccess is:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} r\/([\w\d]+)?\/([\w\d]+)$
    RewriteRule r\/([\w\d]+)?\/([\w\d]+) php/Router.php?called_class=$1&called_method=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Can you expand a little bit more about what it is that you're doing and what is your setup? which bit of Azure are you using? what did you try in the web.config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved.
This is web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
   <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="rule1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="r\/([\w\d]+)?\/([\w\d]+)"  />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/php/Router.php?called_class={R:1}&amp;called_method={R:2}"  appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```